# "unexpected symbol" in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

> Error: unexpected symbol

Add ; to separate calculation order but doesn't work

```
mm=0:10
ss=0:10
for(i in 0:10)
{ w=i/10 xy=w*x+(1-w)*y mm[i+1]=mean(xy) ss[i+1]=sd(xy) print(c(mean(xy),sd(xy)),digits=4) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a semicolon after every expression:

```
mm=0:10
ss=0:10
for(i in 0:10)
{ w=i/10; xy=w*x+(1-w)*y; mm[i+1]=mean(xy); ss[i+1]=sd(xy); print(c(mean(xy),sd(xy)),digits=4); }
```